# How to save data using winform datagridview in entityframework

Tags: datagridview

I am working on winform datagridview and new to entity framework. I insert 10 rows to datagridview and want to save all rows to database table using entity framework. In traditional ado.net i iterate on each datagridview row and save each row one by one, but i am looking a better way in entity framework to achieve this functionality.... Can anyone please help me to save data to database table using datagridview through entityframework with better and fast code????

I shall be very thankful for timely help as this is my first thread on stack overflow.....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach with EF:

```
// declarations
myEntities context = new myEntities();

// form load
dgvItems.DataSource = context.MyEntity;

//form closed
context.Dispose();

//save button
context.SaveChanges();
```